# Bootstrap Carousel - change cycle direction

Tags: jquery, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

is it possible to change the cycle-direction of twitters bootstrap carousel?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel

**I want it to autoplay like this:**

(i have 3 images)

First Image | Last (Third) Image | Second Image | (restart) First Image | ...

So it should move the images out of the right, not out of the left side of my carousel.

*thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Re-order them before you initialize the carousel

```
[].reverse.apply($('.carousel .item')).appendTo(".carousel .carousel-inner");
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

Edit: demo of first line, the initialization would require more scripts added to fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/b6Y9v/

Answer (score 0):

I was needing to get a new feature for the buttons, the feature was:
when the mouse is over the left or the right button in the carousel, the carousel must begin to move.

It was easy to do for the left button, when it is cycling forward, but when i have to do the same in reverse direction, the carousel moves only 1 step backward, and only 1, then, it stops it.

So i help myself with the `setInterval` function

```
onmouseover 
 control = setInterval( "$('#" + name_carrousel + "_next_button').cyclenext()", 200 );

onmouseleave
            clearInterval( control );
            $('#' + name_carrousel).carousel('pause');
```

I also made a little change at the controls :

```
<!-- Controls -->
<a data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-generic" class="left carousel-control" id="carousel-example-generic_prev_button">
  <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-generic" class="right carousel-control" id="carousel-example-generic_next_button">
  <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

The change are the 
  `id="carousel-example-generic_prev_button"`
and
  `id="carousel-example-generic_next_button"`
that change help us to find by the selector.

That is the base of the code below, and it worked.

The code below, is not easy to understand, because is engaged in a jquery library. And it must work with several carrousels, so the control variable, is an array.

globalbootstrap.js

```
$(function() {


    $(document).ready(function(){

        carousel_params_custom = { name_carrousel: 'carousel-example-generic' , time_interval: 200 };
        $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel ).launch_carrousel( carousel_params_custom );

    });



});





jquery.customcarrousel.js


(function($){

    $.fn.extend({
        controlcarrousel: []
        ,
        cyclenext:function(){
            return this.each(function(){
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).carousel({
                    interval:  carousel_params_custom.time_interval
                    ,slide:'next'
                    ,wrap:true
                });
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).carousel('cycle');                
            });
        }
        ,
        cycleprev:function(){
            return this.each(function(){
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).carousel({
                    interval:  carousel_params_custom.time_interval
                    ,slide:'prev'
                    ,wrap:true
                });
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).carousel('cycle');                
            });
        }
        ,
        launch_carrousel:function(carousel_params_custom){

           $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel + '_prev_button').mouseover(function(){
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).controlcarrousel[ carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel ] = setInterval( "$('#" + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel + "_prev_button').cycleprev()", carousel_params_custom.time_interval );
            });

           $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel + '_prev_button').mouseleave(function(){
                clearInterval( $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).controlcarrousel[ carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel ] );
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).carousel('pause');
            });


           $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel + '_next_button').mouseover(function(){
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).controlcarrousel[ carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel ]  = setInterval( "$('#" + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel + "_next_button').cyclenext()", carousel_params_custom.time_interval );
            });

           $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel + '_next_button').mouseleave(function(){
                clearInterval( $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).controlcarrousel[ carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel ] );
                $('#' + carousel_params_custom.name_carrousel).carousel('pause');
            });            

        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution used for rtl cycling of the carousel, it's a simple override:

[Twitter Bootstrap Carousel cycle items right to left ( RTL ) reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877562/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-cycle-items-right-to-left-rtl-reversed)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the direction of the bootstrap carousel sliding by calling 'next' and 'previous' in your jquery/js. In my case I've to change the slide direction every 5 seconds right to left and left to right. Here is the code for that. Hope this helps.

```
            var $carousel = $('.carousel');

            var dirFlag = false;

            setInterval(function(){
                dirFlag = !dirFlag;
                if(dirFlag == true) {
                    $carousel.carousel('next');
                } else {
                    $carousel.carousel('prev');
                }
            }, 5000);
```