# Bootstrap JS 3 carousel rotate Left To Right

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using bootstrap 3 carousel  to rotate images on the banner.
Is there any attribute i can add to my code to force the slides to be flipped RTL or LTR? if not how can it possibly be done? here's my code:

```
    $('.carousel').carousel({
         interval: 3000,
         pause: "hover",
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Carousel cycle items right to left ( RTL ) reversed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877562/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-cycle-items-right-to-left-rtl-reversed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no [option](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-options) to change the direction of a Bootstrap Carousel.

You'll have to do it yourself. You can override the function of Bootstrap by running this code before yours.

```
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.next = function () {
  if (this.sliding) return;
  return this.slide('prev');
};

$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.prev = function () {
  if (this.sliding) return;
  return this.slide('next');
};
```

But be carefull, it will change the direction for all Carousel on page and the controls will be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

## How to control Bootstrap carousels by CSS classes

You can define CSS-classes and assign them to your carousels at your discretion.
For example:

1. The `.wide-and-responsive` class makes images wide and responsive.
2. The `.rtl` class changes the direction of the transition.
3. The `.rtl-indicators` class changes the order of the indicators.
4. You can also set all these properties together, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37714229/6263942).

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* Make the images wide and responsive. */
.wide-and-responsive img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Change the direction of the transition. */
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .rtl .item.next,
  .rtl .active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .rtl .item.prev,
  .rtl .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

/* Change the order of the indicators. Return them to the center of the slide. */
.rtl-indicators .carousel-indicators {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.rtl-indicators .carousel-indicators li {
  float: right;
  margin: 1px 4px;
}
.rtl-indicators .carousel-indicators .active {
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<h1>How to control Bootstrap carousels by CSS classes</h1>

<h2><span class="label label-default">.wide-and-responsive</span> makes the images wide and responsive</h2>
<div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide wide-and-responsive" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<h2><span class="label label-default">.rtl</span> changes the direction of the transition</h2>
<div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide rtl" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<h2><span class="label label-default">.rtl-indicators</span> changes the order of the indicators</h2>
<div id="carousel-3" class="carousel slide rtl-indicators" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-3" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-3" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<h2>All together now</h2>
<div id="carousel-4" class="carousel slide wide-and-responsive rtl rtl-indicators" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-4" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-4" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-4" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/600x150/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-4" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-4" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Change the direction of the transition. Left To Right in **bootstrap4 by css Only***/

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .active.carousel-item-left, .carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-right) {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    .active.carousel-item-right, .carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-left) {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.