# Carousel reverse animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any possibility to reverse the carousel rotate direction, say left to right, generally it behaves to rotate right to left. data-ride="carousel" change?

Comment: which carousel are you using?

Comment: @PrajwalShrestha http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel2&stacked=h

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877562/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-cycle-items-right-to-left-rtl-reversed